# How should you structure your firebase projects?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, github-actions, firebase-hosting, directory-structure

I'm working on a firebase project and was wondering how you typically structure your directories for a firebase frontend and firebase functions?

I played with nesting the `functions` directory inside the frontend project's repo like so:

```
|-frontend
  |-functions
    |-node_modules
    |-src
  |-node_modules
  |-src
```

This fine, but in a TypeScript project, having a nested node_modules produces errors along the lines of some `types` being duplicated.

As of right now, I have both the `frontend` repo and the `functions` repo separated but seeing some inconsistency in Github Actions for the CI of the functions repo.

I'm just trying to figure out what would be the best way to go about this.

Comment: Hi @major94 thank you for contributing to StackOverflow. In this question, it sounds like you're more asking for an opinion on how to do something. StackOverflow isn't well equipped to handle "best practices" questions. If you are able to rephrase your question mentioning a specific issue you're having, feel free to edit it. I don't know enough about this other TypeScript project you're working on, so it's hard for me and others to give you a concrete answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i had the same question. i used to store the the cloud functions in a separate repo. im wondering if its better to  store them in the frontend repo

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for what the best structure would be, surely it's contextual. My goal was to get to started quickly.

What I do have a solution for is the duplicate type errors when nesting `functions` directory in your frontend repo like so:

```
|-frontend
  |-functions
    |-node_modules
    |-src
    |-tsconfig.json
  |-node_modules
  |-src
```

We need to specify `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json` of the `functions` directory or else types get traversed up to the parent `node_modules`.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```